# Can't remove an h1 element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this website http://webr.hol.es/  and under my slider there is a `<h1>home </h1>` . I want to delete it. I found the css class and deleted, but after this when I go to my blog section I can't see my blog titles anymore. Can you tell me a way to access the entire html just like I do with inspect element?

I want to give it an additional class and remote just that class. But I can't find where it is. I need a plugin to see my website's code like I see with inspect element or maybe a hint that helps me to find where is that element in my source code.

Comment: Just so you know, you have a typo on the last picture. It says "Never give un...", I assume you want it to say "Never give in..."

Comment: Just search for it in your source code after you find it with inspect element. In this case you would paste `<h1 class="title-post">Home</h1>` in your source code search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following CSS rule:

```
.page-id-13 h1 { display: none; }
```

That's the page ID of that page (as shown in the developer tools of the browser, should be unique as Wordpress assigns it automatically), combined with the h1 tag, preventing that one (and only on that page) to be displayed.

Addition: If that doesn't work, add "!important", like `display: none !important;`. But when i tried it in the developer tools in my browser, it worked without that.

Comment: thank you very much! It worked. Can you tell me where did you find the id of the page in the developer tools? I will need to know in the future.

Comment: Directly in the `body` tag (among other classes). The other IDs will look similar, just with a different number.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to tell you where to find that H1 tag in your HTML without knowing what type of CMS you are using along with its theme. If you're not using a CMS, you can open your web root in a code editor and do a search/replace for `<h1 class="title-post">Home</h1>`

Otherwise, add this to your CSS:

```
.title-post { display:none !important; }
```

Please add more information to your post so you don't have to use this (admittedly) hack.

Comment: `!important` should not be a go-to solution for these sort of issues, however with the lack of clear structure given by the Question then this solution works, but there will be better solutions once more details are established.

Comment: It'll probably work without `!important` anyway, but if it doesn't, adding `body `  in front often increases specificity enough to do the job. The problem is that this selector will kill all H1 titles site-wide.

Comment: @Martin - I edited my answer. I agree with your comment.

Comment: @isherwood, not quite. It will kill all H1 titles with the class .title-post sitewide which is the request of the OP.

Comment: It wasn't clear in your answer that the class was a modification.

Comment: That's because it wasn't. The class assigned to the H1 tag, for the title as mentioned by the OP, was an original implementation by the CMS. My answer simply tacks on a display override to the pre-existing title-post class.

Comment: Thank you guys! I used wordpress cms for that website. I managed to resolve this problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is a WordPress site, so there likely is no `h1` tag that you can simply remove or edit on a per-page basis. It's built into the PHP templates. Even if you find it, your approach isn't ideal. Hacking up templates should be a last resort, and should only be done via overrides that don't affect the core template files.

Look for options in your admin panel to show or hide the title for that page. If you can, add a page class to just that page and select the element like so (there's probably only one `h1` element):

```
.some-page-class h1 {}
```

Comment: Someone said the same thing, and it worked. Thanks anyway :D You guys are awesome